# How to separate based on multiple delimitors (consecutive whitespaces)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a txt that looks like this

```
Layer_00 : 3.46ms   Layer_01 : 3.40ms   Layer_02 : 3.56ms   Layer_03 : 3.49ms   Layer_04 : 3.44ms
Layer_05 : 3.45ms   Layer_06 : 3.44ms   Layer_07 : 3.46ms   Layer_08 : 3.45ms   Layer_09 : 3.48ms
Layer_10 : 3.48ms   Layer_11 : 3.48ms   Layer_12 : 3.57ms   Layer_13 : 3.54ms   Layer_14 : 3.60ms
Layer_15 : 3.58ms   Layer_16 : 3.59ms   Layer_17 : 3.57ms   Layer_18 : 3.55ms   Layer_19 : 3.57ms
Layer_20 : 3.58ms   Layer_21 : 3.57ms   Layer_22 : 3.52ms   Layer_23 : 3.56ms   Layer_24 : 3.47ms
```

I want to separate them with ':' and 3 consecutive whitespaces
does anyone know how to achievie it?
I tried the

```
pd.read_csv('text.txt', sep = '[:,   ]', header = None)
```

but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just process them by hand.  `pandas.read_csv` is convenient, but it only works if your data happens to match the formats it can read.

```
import re
data = []
for line in open('text.txt'):
    data.append( re.split(r'\s[\s:]\s', line.rstrip()) )
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close just the 'sep' arg was to be defined in another way along with an engine param.
One way of doing it is providing sep with different separators.

**Two Solutions**

**With regex**

```
pd.read_csv('text.txt', engine='python', sep=r"\s*:\s*|\s+", header = None)
```

**Without Regex**

```
pd.read_csv('text.txt', engine='python', sep="   | : ", header = None)
```

**Output**

```
    0           1       2           3       4   5   6   7   8   9
0   Layer_00    3.46ms  Layer_01    3.40ms  Layer_02    3.56ms  Layer_03    3.49ms  Layer_04    3.44ms
1   Layer_05    3.45ms  Layer_06    3.44ms  Layer_07    3.46ms  Layer_08    3.45ms  Layer_09    3.48ms
2   Layer_10    3.48ms  Layer_11    3.48ms  Layer_12    3.57ms  Layer_13    3.54ms  Layer_14    3.60ms
3   Layer_15    3.58ms  Layer_16    3.59ms  Layer_17    3.57ms  Layer_18    3.55ms  Layer_19    3.57ms
4   Layer_20    3.58ms  Layer_21    3.57ms  Layer_22    3.52ms  Layer_23    3.56ms  Layer_24    3.47ms
```

Answer (score 0):

This data doesn't look like a csv, in that there aren't headers and columns. It looks more like a list of key/value pairs. You could try parsing your file and separating the pairs with regex:

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    pairs = re.findall('(Layer_\d+)\s:\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', file.read())
pairs = [(k, float(v)) for k,v in pairs]
df = pd.DataFrame(pairs)
```

That will give a df that looks like this:

```
           0     1
0   Layer_00  3.46
1   Layer_01  3.40
2   Layer_02  3.56
3   Layer_03  3.49
4   Layer_04  3.44
5   Layer_05  3.45
6   Layer_06  3.44
7   Layer_07  3.46
8   Layer_08  3.45
9   Layer_09  3.48
10  Layer_10  3.48
11  Layer_11  3.48
12  Layer_12  3.57
13  Layer_13  3.54
14  Layer_14  3.60
15  Layer_15  3.58
16  Layer_16  3.59
17  Layer_17  3.57
18  Layer_18  3.55
19  Layer_19  3.57
20  Layer_20  3.58
21  Layer_21  3.57
22  Layer_22  3.52
23  Layer_23  3.56
24  Layer_24  3.47
```